# What is the 131072 in the call to lo_open()

Tags: postgresql, export, database-internals, blob

ByteA to BLOB conversions typically make a call to `lo_open()`,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_lo(bytea)
RETURNS oid AS $$
DECLARE
  loid oid;
  fd integer;
  bytes integer;
BEGIN
  loid := lo_creat(-1);
  fd := lo_open(loid, 131072); -- <<< --==HERE==--
  bytes := lowrite(fd, $1);
  IF (bytes != LENGTH($1)) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not all data copied to blob';
  END IF;
  PERFORM lo_close(fd);
  RETURN loid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

In the above what is

```
fd := lo_open(loid, 131072);
```

You can see others asking this same [question here](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Viewing-TEXT-objects-tp2197301p2197308.html),

> The number `131072` is some flag I couldn't find what means, and 999999999 is the max read size, but I could read the value anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This variable is called the "mode parameter" and it's the int representation of `INV_READ` (`x'20000'`)

```
-- lo_open(lobjId oid, mode integer) returns integer
-- The mode parameter to lo_open uses two constants:
--   INV_READ  = 0x20000
--   INV_WRITE = 0x40000
```

You can see the integer representation like this,

```
SELECT CAST( x'20000' AS integer);
  int4  
--------
 131072
(1 row)
```

Personally, I would rather use `x'20000'` which I find to be more explicit. You can see `INV_READ` mentioned in a comment in [`largeobject.source`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/a570feaf927b73c5036fa47ea949ca51f2687950/src/test/regress/input/largeobject.source#L35), and you can see it defined it in the code at [`libpq-fs.h`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c7b8998ebbf310a156aa38022555a24d98fdbfb4/src/include/libpq/libpq-fs.h#L21).

In the event you ever see `262144` that's the numified representation of `INV_WRITE` (`0x40000`).